# Attach images to body parts

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to attach some images to user's head and fists but it seems I can't position it correctly. Images are constantly too much below head and fists.

I have this XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="KinectD.Game1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2013"
  xmlns:WpfViewers="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;assembly=Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800"
Title="Game1">

<Canvas>
    <k:KinectRegion x:Name="kinectRegion" Canvas.Left="630">
            <k:KinectCircleButton Label="Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="MenuButtonOnClick" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="Images/smile.png" Height="30"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </k:KinectCircleButton>

    </k:KinectRegion>

    <k:KinectUserViewer k:KinectRegion.KinectRegion="{Binding ElementName=kinectRegion}" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <k:KinectSensorChooserUI HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="sensorChooserUi" /><WpfViewers:KinectColorViewer Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="480" Width="640" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Kinect="{Binding ElementName=sensorChooserUi, Path=KinectSensorChooser.Kinect, Mode=OneWay}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    <Image x:Name="rightEllipse" Canvas.Left="670" Source="Images/glove_right.png" Height="100" Width="70" Margin="0,400,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Image x:Name="leftEllipse" Canvas.Left="670" Source="Images/glove_left.png" Height="100" Width="70" Margin="0,300,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Image x:Name="headImage" Canvas.Left="670" Source="Images/smile.png" Height="70" Width="70" Margin="0,200,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

</Canvas>
```

And this XAML.CS:

```
public partial class Game1 : Page
{
    #region "Kinect"
    private KinectSensorChooser sensorChooser;
    #endregion

    bool closing = false;
    const int skeletonCount = 6;
    Skeleton[] allSkeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonCount];

    public Game1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // initialize the sensor chooser and UI
        this.sensorChooser = new KinectSensorChooser();
        //Assign the sensor chooser with the sensor chooser from the mainwindow. 
        //We are reusing the sensorchoosing declared in the first window that can in contact with kinect
        this.sensorChooser = Generics.GlobalKinectSensorChooser;
        //subscribe to the sensorChooserOnKinectChanged event
        this.sensorChooser.KinectChanged += SensorChooserOnKinectChanged;
        //Assign Kinect Sensorchooser to the sensorchooser we got from our static class
        this.sensorChooserUi.KinectSensorChooser = sensorChooser;

        var parameters = new TransformSmoothParameters
        {
            Smoothing = 0.3f,
            Correction = 0.0f,
            Prediction = 0.0f,
            JitterRadius = 1.0f,
            MaxDeviationRadius = 0.5f
        };
        this.sensorChooser.Kinect.SkeletonStream.Enable(parameters);

        this.sensorChooserUi.KinectSensorChooser.Kinect.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(sensor_AllFramesReady);

        // Bind the sensor chooser's current sensor to the KinectRegion
        var regionSensorBinding = new Binding("Kinect") { Source = this.sensorChooser };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.kinectRegion, KinectRegion.KinectSensorProperty, regionSensorBinding);

        //this.sensorChooser.Kinect.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(sensor_AllFramesReady);



    }

    private void SensorChooserOnKinectChanged(object sender, KinectChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        bool error = false;
        if (args.OldSensor != null)
        {
            try
            {
                args.OldSensor.DepthStream.Range = DepthRange.Default;
                args.OldSensor.SkeletonStream.EnableTrackingInNearRange = false;
                args.OldSensor.DepthStream.Disable();
                args.OldSensor.SkeletonStream.Disable();

                args.OldSensor.ColorStream.Disable();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                // KinectSensor might enter an invalid state while enabling/disabling streams or stream features.
                // E.g.: sensor might be abruptly unplugged.
                error = true;
            }
        }

        if (args.NewSensor != null)
        {
            try
            {
                args.NewSensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
                args.NewSensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
                args.NewSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                error = true;
                // KinectSensor might enter an invalid state while enabling/disabling streams or stream features.
                // E.g.: sensor might be abruptly unplugged.
            }
        }

        if (!error)
            kinectRegion.KinectSensor = args.NewSensor;
    }

    void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (closing)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Get a skeleton
        Skeleton first = GetFirstSkeleton(e);

        if (first == null)
        {
            return;
        }



        //set scaled position
        ScalePosition(headImage, first.Joints[JointType.Head]);
        ScalePosition(leftEllipse, first.Joints[JointType.HandLeft]);
        ScalePosition(rightEllipse, first.Joints[JointType.HandRight]);

        GetCameraPoint(first, e);

    }

    void GetCameraPoint(Skeleton first, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {

        using (DepthImageFrame depth = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            if (depth == null ||
                this.sensorChooser.Kinect == null)
            {
                return;
            }


            //Map a joint location to a point on the depth map
            //head
            DepthImagePoint headDepthPoint =
                this.sensorChooser.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(first.Joints[JointType.Head].Position, depth.Format);
            //left hand
            DepthImagePoint leftDepthPoint =
                this.sensorChooser.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(first.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position, depth.Format);
            //right hand
            DepthImagePoint rightDepthPoint =
                this.sensorChooser.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(first.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position, depth.Format);


            //Map a depth point to a point on the color image
            //head
            ColorImagePoint headColorPoint =
                this.sensorChooser.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint(depth.Format, headDepthPoint, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

            //left hand
            ColorImagePoint leftColorPoint =
                this.sensorChooser.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint(depth.Format, leftDepthPoint, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

            //right hand
            ColorImagePoint rightColorPoint =
                this.sensorChooser.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint(depth.Format, rightDepthPoint, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

            //Set location
            CameraPosition(headImage, headColorPoint);
            CameraPosition(leftEllipse, leftColorPoint);
            CameraPosition(rightEllipse, rightColorPoint);
        }
    }


    Skeleton GetFirstSkeleton(AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrameData = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (skeletonFrameData == null)
            {
                return null;
            }


            skeletonFrameData.CopySkeletonDataTo(allSkeletons);

            //get the first tracked skeleton
            Skeleton first = (from s in allSkeletons
                              where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                              select s).FirstOrDefault();

            return first;

        }
    }

    private void CameraPosition(FrameworkElement element, ColorImagePoint point)
    {
        //Divide by 2 for width and height so point is right in the middle 
        // instead of in top/left corner
        Canvas.SetLeft(element, point.X - element.Width / 2);
        Canvas.SetTop(element, point.Y - element.Height / 2);

        //Canvas.SetLeft(element, point.X - element.Width);
        //Canvas.SetTop(element, point.Y - element.Height);

    }

    private void ScalePosition(FrameworkElement element, Joint joint)
    {
        //convert the value to X/Y
        //Joint scaledJoint = joint.ScaleTo(1280, 720); 



        //convert & scale (.3 = means 1/3 of joint distance)
        //Joint scaledJoint = joint.ScaleTo(640, 480, .3f, .3f);
        Joint scaledJoint = joint.ScaleTo(640, 480, .3f, .3f);

        Canvas.SetLeft(element, scaledJoint.Position.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(element, scaledJoint.Position.Y);

    }

    private void MenuButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.sensorChooser.KinectChanged -= SensorChooserOnKinectChanged;
        (Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("_mainFrame") as Frame).Source = new Uri("MainMenu.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

It seems it reads skeleton correctly because images immediately move to user's area but not correctly. It seems to me images are moved correctly horizontally but not vertically. They are below user's head and fists but I would say some 200 pixels too much below. Any ideas what could be a problem?

Comment: Where is the `ScaleTo` function coming from for `Joint`?  Coding4Fun?  When you run the application, is it 640x480 pixels?  If not, the values in your `ScaleTo` need to match accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it is from `Coding4Fun`. The application is 800x600 and image inside for camera is 640x480. I changed values to 800x600 but it's still the same. Maybe I'm missing something in the code.